# How to solve Error: FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0 in paused on promise rejection

Tags: flutter, dart, http, flutter-web, put

I am trying to update my database table row using http put request in flutter web app. My backend server working fine and able to put data on database using postman app.
And from flutter app also updating the data But the app stuck with below errors. And How to solve the issue?

**Below error is from the browser Console and/or Network tab:**

> Error: FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0 in paused on promise rejection.

**Below error is from Browser_client.dart:**

```
unawaited(xhr.onLoad.first.then((_) {
  var body = (xhr.response as ByteBuffer).asUint8List();
  completer.complete(StreamedResponse(
      ByteStream.fromBytes(body), xhr.status!,
      contentLength: body.length,
      request: request,
      headers: xhr.responseHeaders,
      reasonPhrase: xhr.statusText));
}));
```

**Below error from debug console:**

```
> ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'API':
> InternalError: No frame with index 14. ChromeProxyService: Failed to
> evaluate expression 'Completer': InternalError: No frame with index
> 14. ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'xhr.response': InternalError: No frame with index 14. ChromeProxyService: Failed to
> evaluate expression 'completer.complete': InternalError: No frame with
> index 14. ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression
> 'completer': InternalError: No frame with index 14.
```

**Below is my API:**

```
Future<Company> updatedata(
  id,
  company,
  name,
  address,
  phone,

) async {
  Uri url = Uri.parse("http://-- Link --/$id");
  var response = await http.put(url,
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        "company": company,
        "name": name,
        "address": address,
        "phone": phone,
      }));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Company.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to update.');
  }
}
```

Below error comes on terminal while running the web app with the command "flutter run -d chrome" :

> ```
> > Error: FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at
> > position 0
> >     at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:55164/dart_sdk.js:5067:11)
> >     at Object._parseJson (http://localhost:55164/dart_sdk.js:51151:19)
> >     at JsonDecoder.convert (http://localhost:55164/dart_sdk.js:48968:22)
> >     at JsonCodec.decode (http://localhost:55164/dart_sdk.js:48661:48)
> >     at updatedata (http://localhost:55164/packages/webappmysql/bridg/company_api.dart.lib.js:40:87)
> >     at updatedata.next (<anonymous>)
> >     at http://localhost:55164/dart_sdk.js:40571:33
> >     at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:55164/dart_sdk.js:40441:59)
> >     at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:55164/dart_sdk.js:35363:29)
> >     at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:55164/dart_sdk.js:35931:49)
> >     at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:55164/dart_sdk.js:35969:17)
> >     at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:55164/dart_sdk.js:35817:23)
> >     at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:55164/dart_sdk.js:35838:35)
> >     at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:55164/dart_sdk.js:40708:13)
> >     at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:55164/dart_sdk.js:40714:13)
> >     at http://localhost:55164/dart_sdk.js:36191:9
> ```

Comment: Use `print(response.body);` to see the contents of the response before trying to decode it.

Comment: It prints - Updated Successfully.

Comment: The string `Updated Successfully` is not valid JSON, which is why you cannot parse it. The error message hints at this saying, in essence, "you can't have a U in the first character"

Comment: It seems that your server responds to verb `PUT` with simple text, rather than a JSON encoded company object.

Comment: In this case how can we solve this. What to do?

Comment: Change your method to return `Future<bool>` and change the return line to `return response.body == 'Updated Successfully';` If you really want to return a `Company` you'll have to (presumably) perform a `GET` after the update to fetch the updated company data.

Comment: Actually i am calling these   id,
  ``company = companyController?.text,
  name = nameController?.text,
  address = addressControllers?.text,
  phone = phoneControllers.?text,`` from form fields TextEditingController as variables .

Comment: Which is better method return``Future<bool> or Company method``?

Comment: @RichardHeap  I have changed to Future<bool> and return line. Now it's Working fine. It is an Awesome solution. Thank you Very much..

Answer (score 0):

You can change `updatedata()` to return Future and change the return line to return `response.body == 'Updated Successfully';`

If you need to return a Company object, you might need to perform an http GET to fetch the updated company data after the updating the data using http PUT.